# cuda "expected a type specifier"

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I am getting an error in line 10 `__global__ void kernel` .I must be doing something wrong?
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define F 20

__global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob, F)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x;
    double maxfit;
    maxfit=dev_fitness[0];
    if(i<F)
    {
        if(dev_fitness[i]>maxfit)
            maxfit=dev_fitness[i];
    }
    if(i<F)
    {
        dev_prob[i]=(0.9*(dev_fitness[i]/maxfit))+0.1;
    }
}

double prob[F];
double fitness[F];
int main()
{   
    double* dev_fitness;
    size_t fitnessSize= F*sizeof(double);
    cudaMalloc(&dev_fitness,fitnessSize);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_fitness,fitness,fitnessSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //--------------
    double* dev_prob;
    size_t probSize=F*sizeof(double);
    cudaMalloc(&dev_prob,probSize);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_prob,prob,probSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

            kernel <<<F,1>>> (dev_fitness,dev_prob,F);
            cudaMemcpy (fitness,dev_fitness,fitnessSize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaMemcpy (prob,dev_prob,probSize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaFree (dev_fitness);
            cudaFree (dev_prob);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> __global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob, F)
> //                                                         ^^^
> ```

You are attempting to pass a literal (the macro `F` expands to `20`) as a function argument, i.e.:

> ```
> __global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob, 20)
> ```

This is just not correct. Recall that macros are basic text find-and-replace that occurs before your code is compiled.

In fact, you shall not emplace *any* expression within an argument list.

Fortunately for you, your macro is already globally accessible within the whole file, so you don't need to pass it into the function at all.

That is, simply write:

```
  __global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `#define`, the macro gets expanded literally:

```
#define F 20
__global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob, F) {
```

into :

```
__global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob, 20) {
```

However, you can't of course use `20` in function declaration!
So either

1. Don't use that param at all:

   `__global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob)`
   The code will work, because macros (thus, `F`) are globally visible (they are *pre*-processed, before compilation).
2. Change that param to appropriate variable:

   `__global__ void kernel(double* dev_fitness,double* dev_prob, double Fparam)`
   And the code inside function to take use of Fparam.

   Then, you can call `kernel` supplying `F` as a last parameter.